# Clearing Query Cache Using JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, query-cache

I want to clear the query cache using JPA, I am having the reference of EntityManager with me.

Please suggest how can I achieve this.

I am using hibernate 3.0 as an implementation of JPA with Stateless EJBs.

One way that I discover is to getDelegate from EntityManager and then getting the SessionFactory and then call evict on that.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

((JpaCache) getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getCache()).clearQueryCache(namedQueryName)